# Actions occurring while a button is pressed - swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my swift project I have a button and I want to print on a label how much time this button has been pressed.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Try yourLabel.text = NSDate.description()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how button is created programmatically and prints a text in label when button is pressed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let myFirstButton = UIButton()
        myFirstButton.setTitle("Tap Me", forState: .Normal)
        myFirstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        myFirstButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 320, 40)
        myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
    }

func pressed(sender: UIButton!) 
{
   yourLabelName.text=@"Your Text is here"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to DHEERAJ's answer, you just need to add following code in `func pressed(sender: UIButton!)` to achieve what you need:

```
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
yourLabelName.text = dateString
```

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

To show how many times the button has been clicked you could class variable.

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {

var counter : Int!
@IBOutlet weak var yourLabelName: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    counter = 1
    let myFirstButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, 50, 320, 40))

    myFirstButton.setTitle("Tap Me", forState: .Normal)
    myFirstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:",forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
}

func pressed(sender: UIButton!)
{
    yourLabelName.text = "Pressed : \(counter)"
    counter = counter + 1
}
```

}